# Setting the module path for gulp-jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine, gulp

I'm trying to unit test some Javascript code with jasmine which uses a peg parser. The peg parser is built at build time.

Unfortunately I haven't found out how to tell jasmine where the dynamically built parser is.

So far I've got:

```
gulp.task('parser', () => {
    return gulp.src("src/parser.peg")
        .pipe(peg())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(".obj"))
});

gulp.task('test', ["parser"], () => {
    return gulp.src(["tests/**/*.js", "src/**/*.js", ".obj/parser.js"])
        .pipe(jasmine())
});
```

Now, by the time the tests run, the parser is correctly built and put in `.obj`; but it's not on the module path, so the test loads the real code, the real code tries to `import parser from "parser"`, and the test fails.

I could change the real code to import `../obj/parser` instead of `parser`, but that will fail in production, of course. I need to somehow tell jasmine to find modules in `.obj`. How?

Comment: What if you use an external variable, change its value in `parser` task accordingly, then use it when calculating pathes for `test`? (like $objPath + '/parser.js', or something?)

Comment: How would I do that?